# Create variable to a path JSON is an action performed by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Need to load the "summary" of each item are all together starting from a JSON.
I created this variable but this seems wrong because I always returns the first item, not the current item.

javascript:

```
// it seems to be wrong
var description = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
    return item.summary;

});

var i = 0;

$(".selected").each(function () {
    if ($(this).css("background") == "red") i = $(this).index();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2NmnB/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Call Ajax Key Enter
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {             
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('.description').html(description[$(".selected").index()]);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this modification http://jsfiddle.net/2NmnB/4/

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    var x = $('li').index( $('.selected'));

                    $('.description').html(description[x]);
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```